# is Google Analytics for analyzing users behaviors only?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, dashboard, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I want to create a dashboard for my firebase database using google analytics.
But I'm wondering do google analytics analyze the behaviors only? Can I analyze specific variables from my database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom-parameters to add details (i.e. from your database) to an hit: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it